Space Exploration SE only in "read-mode". What is happening there?
Yesterday, Space Exploration SE stopped working for a while (when accessed through a browser on a PC).

At the same time, when accessing the site through a smartphone, the functionality is preserved, and one of the users answered my question.
And now I observe that users come in, new questions appear, which means that site is fully functional.

What's happening?

This has been happening a lot, see:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401510/read-only-mode-activated-for-me-but-seemingly-it-is-not-a-maintenance-thing and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399904/stack-overflow-in-read-only-mode-for-past-2-days] for examples.

I cleared the browser (cache, cookies, etc.) for the entire time. And everything worked.

Post 23rd July release, incidents were reported that the sites were on read only. It was fixed according to this ticket: https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/f1490159-6b45-4b27-8a2b-cbcc1eaa05b1
